# Random coefficient GARCH(1,1): Existence of solution

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, time-series, law-of-large-numbers

I am studying the random coefficient GARCH(1,1)-model and I am using the paper "[Random coefficient GARCH(1,1) model with i.i.d. coefficients](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10986-005-0015-6.pdf)" from A. Klivecka.

We have the GARCH(1,1)-model given by

\begin{equation}
r_t=\epsilon_t \sigma_t, \;\;\;\; \sigma_t^2=a_t r_{t-1}^2 + b_t \sigma_{t-1}^2 + c_t \;\;
\end{equation} with i.i.d. coefficients $(a_t,b_t,c_t)$ and $\epsilon_t$, $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

We are using the notation
\begin{equation*}
\xi_t := \epsilon_t^2 , \;\;\;  x_t := r_t^2, \;\;\; V_t:=\sigma_t^2, \;\;\; A_t :=a_t \xi_{t-1} + b_t
\end{equation*}
and rewrite the model above as follows
\begin{equation}
x_t = \xi_t V_t , \;\; V_t = A_t V_{t-1} + c_t.
\end{equation}
By a solution of this we mean any sequence $\{x_t,v_t, t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ of random variables such that the equation holds a.s. for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Now we get a formal solution by iteration as follows
\begin{equation}
x_t = \xi_t c_t + \xi_t A_t c_{t-1} + \xi_t A_t A_{t-1} c_{t-2} + \dots = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \xi_t c_{t-i} \prod_{j=1}^{i} A_{t-j+1}
\end{equation}
I got stuck at Proposition 1, which says, that this iterated solution is unique as follows:

**Proposition 1**

Let one of the following conditions be satisfied:
\begin{equation}
-\infty \leq \mathbb{E}[\log A_0] < 0 \;\;\; \operatorname{and} \;\;\; \mathbb{E}[\max(\log c_0,0)] < \infty
\end{equation}
or\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(A_0=0) > 0.
\end{equation}
Then the series above $x_t = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \xi_t c_{t-i} \prod_{j=1}^{i} A_{t-j+1}$ converges absolutely a.s. and represents a unique (bounded in probability, strictly stationary and nonanticipative) solution.

The uniqueness-part and the properties in brackets are clear for me, so I don't give the definitions of the terms used there. My problem is the part of the proof, where is shown that the sum converges a.s..

**The proof is as follows:**
By the first condition and the independency of $\{A_t\}$ and $\{c_t\}$, by the strong law of large numbers we obtain 
\begin{equation*}
\limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{k}\left( \log c_{t-k-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{k} \log A_{t-i} \right) < 0 \;\; \operatorname{a.s.}
\end{equation*}
Hence,
\begin{equation*}
\limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \log (A_{t-1} \dots A_{t-k} c_{t-k-1})^\frac{1}{k} < 0 \; \operatorname{or} \; \limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} (A_{t-1} \dots A_{t-k} c_{t-k-1})^\frac{1}{k} < 1 \; \operatorname{a.s.}
\end{equation*}
Therefore by Cauchy's root criterion, the sum converges absolutely a.s.

*I don't get what is happening here. First I don't know how to use the strong law of large numbers, because this is only a property. I also don't know, how we get the log in there and how to apply Cauhcy's root theorem. Now to the second condition:*

The second condition together with $\{A_t\}$ i.i.d. , implies that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \xi_t c_{t-i} \prod_{j=1}^{i} A_{t-j+1}$  is a.s. finite and, therefore, also converges absolutely a.s.

*How do we know, that the sum is finite?*
I know, that $\mathbb{P}(A_0=0) > 0$, so $\mathbb{P}(A_0=0) \in (0,1]$ and $\mathbb{P}(A_0 \neq 0) \in [0,1)$. Since the $A_t$ are i.i.d., this holds for $A_t$ instead of $A_0$. But since there is no propability $\mathbb{P}$ in the product and sum, I don't know how to use this, if it has to be used.

Some help would be really really nice!